# Why does code yields no results on this char comparison?

Tags: c, char

Evening, sorry for beginner question but I have to do a code that receives 7 salutations in different languages, compare to a database, and, if they match, tell which language the salutation was on, if they don't, tell the user the language is unknown.

I think i understood the problem, but my code below doesn't show any results and just closes, can someone tell me why? I know it is very sketchy coding but cant find exactly the mistake. (Telling me a substitute for the multiple variables inside scanf would be much appreciated too).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char en[7][15];
    char id[7][15] = {"HELLO","HOLA","CIAO","HALLO","BOUNJOUR","ZDRAVSTVUJTE","."};
    char re[7][15] = {"INGLES","ESPANOL","ITALIANO","ALEMAN","FRANCES","RUSO","NLS"};
    scanf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s",en[0],en[1],en[2],en[3],en[4],en[5],en[6]);
    int i = 0,j=0,m=1,k=0;
    while(i<8){
        for(j=0;j<7;j++){
            m=strcmp(en[i],id[j]);
            if(m==0 || j==6){
                strcpy(en[i],re[j]);
                k=i+1;
                printf("Caso %s: %s /n",k,en[i]);
                break;
            }
            }
            i++;
    }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying j never gets to 6?

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf`. If input wasn't as expected, not all of the values will actually be set.

Comment: Aside from some strange limits to your loop variabes, the `printf("Caso %s: %s /n",k,en[i]);` line is clearly wrong! You need the `%d` format specifer for an integer argument (`k`), not `%s`; this will cause undefined behaviour, likely causing your program to crash on the first attempted `printf` call.

Comment: Do you have warnings enabled? gcc is telling me for this program, at the `printf` call: `warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]`

Comment: @nicomp it does but i thought that if it gets to 6 it (should) means no language is a match so it should be assigned as unknown, that's why both a match and j==6 are parameters for the if, is it wrong to think this way?

Comment: Tip: Instead of assuming any particular size for those strings, why not `char* id[]` and just let the compiler figure it out? This would also be better expressed in some kind of config file you read in, but hard-coded is at least one way to start solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `printf` function. You are using `%s` format specifier for `k` instead of `%d`. Just change that line to this:

```
printf("Caso %d: %s \n",k,en[i]);
```

Also, the `while` condition `i<8` should be changed to `i<7` since there are 7 cases and not 8.

As for the `scanf`, don't think it's much of an improvement but you can use a `for` loop as well.

Comment: Thank you, the 8 was actually a typo but thanks nonetheless.